# How to get the input in ComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I try to get the combo box value but it cant retrieve the input..I m new using NetBeans software..so its complicated for me..Beside, I need you all to help me solve this matter..Hope someone can help me..

```
public class Lab4 extends javax.swing.JPanel {


    public Lab4() {
        initComponents();

    }


    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 {
        int num1,num2,sum;
        num1=Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
        num2=Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
        sum=num1+num2;
        jTextField1.setText(" "+sum);
    }        
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  {
        int num1,num2,mul;
        num1=Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
        num2=Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
        mul=num1*num2;
        jTextField1.setText(" "+mul);
  }  
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 {
        int num1,num2;
        float div;
        num1=Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
        num2=Integer.parseInt((String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
        div=(float)num1/num2;
        jTextField1.setText(" "+div);
    }      
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 {
        System.exit(0);
    }        
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: do you want to get selected value from combobox ?

Comment: Have you looked at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just as simple as this:

```
nameOfComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

And if your asking how to control the event when any item is selected from the combo box, use the following code (This is how I do it):

```
nameOfComboBox.addActionListener(e->nameOfMethodToHandleEvent());
```

Then just create this method:

```
 nameOfMethodToHandleEvent()
```

And put what you would like to happen when a new Item is selected in the method.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, do you mind re-stating your question here?

Comment: i want to create a simple calculater..i have seen the example use a TextField but i try to use ComboBox in the input value..When i try to run and click button add its cannot get the input in comboBox..

Comment: anyone else can help me..??